# Make Laravel artisan play with vagrant from localhost

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant

When I ssh into my local vagrant machine I can execute all artisan commands. Hower outside of it, any commands that needs database access such as artisan migrate gives `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`. If it is possible, how can I use artisan without having to log in to the vagrant machine?

I would also like to do for example `Artisian::call('migrate')` for example during testing. But that gives the same error.

Comment: You can do it without logging in (AFAIK). Think the `VM` as a remote server and it needs authentication before executing any command.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Are you saying it can be done? Am I just having a bad configuration?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. No it can't be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the `access denied` error is that mysql by default limits access to databases to the local machine. It is possible to open up for remote connections as described [here](http://www.thisprogrammingthing.com/2013/accessing-your-vagrant-vms-mysql-database-from-the-host-computer/), but it wouldn't be a good idea for production environments.

A better way is to add aliases for the commands you want as described [here](http://www.wekeroad.com/2011/10/06/flex-the-power-of-your-mac-terminal/).

For doing calls to artisan etc in code, Laravel has a built in way of running commands on remote servers. First add connection information to the app/config/remote.php file. For vagrant it should look something like this:

```
'connections' => array(

    'production' => array(
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'username'  => 'vagrant',
        'password'  => 'vagrant',
        'key'       => '',
        'keyphrase' => '',
        'root'      => '/vagrant',
    ),

),
```

Then execute artisan migrate like this:

```
SSH::run(array('cd /vagrant', 'php artisan migrate'));
```

You can do more advanced things as well. Here is the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/ssh).